# Python - Web Scraping with Selenium - Graph Data

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, graph

I'm trying to scrape data from a bar chart (Overview - Price Chart ($)), but nothing I've tried returns any information about the chart.
Any tips?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.5615.138 Safari/537.36'  # noqa
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))  # noqa

driver.get("https://www.etf.com/SPY")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

# Scroll to the chart where View All button exist
chart = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-prop-label='Fund Overview Price TR Comparison Chart']")))  # noqa
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", chart)

# Locate View All button and using Javascript to click on that element to avoid "element click intercepted" exception. # noqa
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Max']")))  # noqa
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", element)

# ?????
```